# Unity3D SpaceShooter Mouse movement while upside down

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, mouse

I'm making a 3D space game where you fly a ship. its first person from the cockpit. 
All my movements work like a charm (W/S = speed up/down, Q/R = rotate left/right) and the mouse moves the ship around.

But if I use my rotate buttons, the mouse stays "stuck". Easiest way to explain it is: when I fly normal, moving the mouse up pans the camera up, and down - pans down. 
But if I fly upside down the mouse doesnt seem to notice it and pans the wrong way (inverted). Like it doenst know my rotation. On the side its even weirder. The mouse keeps going up on the initial rotation not on the new one I dont know how to solve it.

What I basicly want to do is also turn the mouse orientation when pressing Q or E

This is my rotate/mouse script:

```
if (Input.GetKey("q"))
     {
         orientationPanel.transform.Rotate(-Vector3.left * 100f * Time.deltaTime);
         cam.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 100f * Time.deltaTime);
         transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 100f * Time.deltaTime);
     }

     if (Input.GetKey("e"))
     {
         orientationPanel.transform.Rotate(Vector3.left * 100f * Time.deltaTime);
         cam.transform.Rotate(-Vector3.forward * 100f * Time.deltaTime); 
         transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 100f * Time.deltaTime);           
     }

     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && Time.time > nextFire)
     {
         nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
         Fire();
     }

     float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
     float mouseY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

     rotY += mouseX * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
     rotX += mouseY * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

     rotX = Mathf.Clamp(rotX, -clampAngle, clampAngle);
     rotZ = orientationPanel.transform.rotation.z;

     Quaternion localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, rotY, rotZ);
     transform.rotation = localRotation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rotate your ship always in local space. If you move mouse to right - always move nose of the ship to right. 
`Rotate(axis, angle, Space.Self);`

For example

```
Rotate(Vector3.up, rotY, Space.Self);
Rotate(Vector3.right, rotX, Space.Self);
```

This will also fix rotation with Q/E, because with

```
Quaternion localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, rotY, rotZ);
     transform.rotation = localRotation;
```

you basically override changes made with

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 100f * Time.deltaTime);
transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 100f * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked :D Can you tell me why my method didnt work? I want to understand the code instead of just copying it :P

Comment: You need to understand what is global and what is local space. Simply: Global is position and rotation relative to imaginary grid in Unity - to the whole world. Local is relative to object itself. If I hold the ship upside-down globally his "left" became "right". But when you are sitting inside of cockpit your "left" always at "left". If you want to turn your local "left" you need to somehow realize where is "left" in global space.

Comment: By the way I think that your method could work if you change 
`transform.rotation = localRotation;`
to 
`transform.localRotation = localRotation;`
but I'm not sure

Comment: transform.localRotation = localRotation; didnt work btw.